# Google App Engine - Website closed the connection

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

so I'm trying to host some code on a Google Cloud Platform VM. I've started with a simple 'Hello, world!' html page. But when I host it and try to connect to the IP I get:

' This Site can't be reached! 
[IP Address] unexpectedly closed the connection '

Has anyone dealt with something like this before? And if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Let me suggest [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) instead of Compute Engine (which I assume you are using) to host applications.

Comment: Yeah i was just looking at comparisons between the two. But do you know why it's closing the connection?

Comment: Is this happening to a particular IP address?.  Which browser are you using? (Try using a different browser). Additionally check the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) of GCP.